# Powershell Job within SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, smo

I am having trouble with a powershell job returning a result set when it runs, it runs successfully but no results. I am running it against a list of servers. If I run the script against a specific server that I know I can connect to, it runs fine and gives results.

This is a script within the sql server agent running powershell. Am I using the SMO object right? Ive tried to use a try/catch (job fails), ive tried to add -ErrorAction "Continue" to the script (job fails), using smo to resolve a server name in order to use the if statement (job succeeds) but no results. Here is the script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue";

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null

$instanceNameList = Get-Content "c:\Scripts\InPutFiles\servers.txt";

$results = @()  

foreach($instanceName in $instanceNameList)
{
$serverObject = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($instanceName)
$serverName = $serverObject.ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS;

if($serverName -ne $null) {
$results += Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "

(My Query is in here!)

" -ServerInstance $instanceName.Name}

$instanceName| Where-Object {$_} | Export-csv 'C:\scripts\HungJobs_UnabletoConnect.csv' -NoTypeInformation 
}
$results| Where-Object {$_} | Export-csv 'C:\scripts\HungJobs.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Mid-way through your script, is the `$scripts` variable being populated properly by the `Invoke-Sqlcmd`?

If so, I'm thinking that you should be able to do away with `Where-Object {$_}` on your last two commands.   `Where-Object` is used as a filter, and in these two cases it doesn't seem to be filtering anything.  You should just be able to directly export the `$instanceName` and `$results` directly to csv.

Comment: I removed the Where-Object portions but still no resultset. Only way for me to get a result set is to run against a list of servers that I know for sure I can connect to and run the query against. I think the trouble is that the servers I cant connect to in that list are messing something up with populating those files.

Comment: Hmm, with the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.smo object, perhaps try this format: `$serverObject = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $InstanceName` and see if that is properly creating the object.

Comment: Tried that, still nothing. The object is definitely working because if i run it against a small list that I know I can connect to all of them, i get a result set. I think something is going wrong when it hits a server in the list that it cant connect to, it errors or something and doesnt give results on the ones it could connect to

Comment: Is your SQL Server Agent allowed to execute Powershell?